# Getting the XML content of a SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, innerhtml

Is there a way to extract the "innerHTML" of a SimpleXMLElement?

For example how would I get `'<div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>'` out of the following XML Code using SimpleXMLElement:

```
<xml>
  <body1>
    <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
  </body1>
  <body2>
    <div><h2>Goodby Moon</h2></div>
  </body2>
</xml>
```

---

I read the documentation and all I came up with was `$xml->body1->asXML();`.
It is almost the right solution but it also adds the root tag:

```
 <body1>
   <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
 </body1>
```

Is it possible to skip the surrounding body1 tags?

---

Edit:

The xml might also look like this:

```
<xml>
  <body1>
    <div><h1>Hello World</h1></div>
    <div><h1>Hello Moon</h1></div>
    Some Text
  </body1>
  <body2>
    <div><h2>Goodby Moon</h2></div>
  </body2>
</xml>
```

As in: http://codepad.org/8ZuRYZOW

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're sure it's a `div` you're looking for :

`$xml->body1[0]->div->asXML();`

else

`$xml->body1[0]->children()->asXML();`

http://codepad.org/QUytim28 else http://codepad.org/hDt28BL6

Comment: (+1) Thanks for your code. However it fails as soon as there is more than one child element. http://codepad.org/EHepjsZg

Comment: That's the reason you need to give more details in your question ;) Here's the solution http://codepad.org/BCxSzP2m

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately it is still not working. I came up with the same idea however it skips plain text. ( See my edited question )

Comment: Well, that's not really a valid XML nor HTML. SimpleXML is simple with valid XML, with a more complex one, you should use DOMDocument, or making it valid, or not going through a XML file.

Comment: Well, well, well, actually, http://codepad.org/m3z15M1p it works thanks to http://www.php.net/manual/fr/simplexmlelement.asXML.php this page's 1st comment. It's ugly, but still...

Comment: @Chouchenos: I modified the code a little bit to prevent wrong replacements: http://codepad.org/jUB8657a

Comment: @Ghommey : :) looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want the [children method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) or you want to use `$xml->body1[ 0 ]->asXML();` (array access)

Comment: Is there any difference between `$xml->body1[ 0 ]->asXML();` and `$xml->body1->asXML();`?

Comment: @Ghommey : The only difference appears if there's more than 1 `<body1>` in your xml